# ng-option preselect value for (key,value) pair when value is an array of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't do a pre-selection in **ng-options** from (key,value) pair when value is a array of objects, although if I use value.property then I can do the pre-selection.

I wrote an example in jsfiddle and I'm able to preselect ng-option by key or value.property but in my case I need the whole array

**edit**
: I edit because [key,value] is [key,Array[Object]] instead of [key,Object]. And I add a new html select code to show right selection based on given answers.

be aware you must pass into ng-model whole set of arrays although the tracking just check array zero. Both structure should be identical.

[Updated JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/rafaparche/pcfLn4xg/8/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
    <select name="first" ng-model="data" ng-options="key as value.templateId for (key, value) in options">
        <option value="">Select template</option>
    </select>
    <div>Data is preselected! = {{data}}</div>
    <br>
    <select name="second" ng-model="data2" ng-options="value.templateId as key for (key, value) in options">
        <option value="">Select template</option>
    </select>
    <div>Data is preselected! = {{data2}}</div>
    <br>
    <select name="third" ng-model="data3" ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in options">
        <option value="">Select template</option>
    </select>
    <div>Data is NOT preselected! = {{data3}}</div> :(

    <select name="forth" ng-model="data4" ng-options="key for (key, value) in                                
    options track by value[0].templateId">

      <option value="">Select template</option>
   </select>

<div>Solution! = {{data4}}</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = "for offer";
    $scope.data2 = "002";
    $scope.data3 = '{ templateId :"001" , color : "yellow"}';

   $scope.data = [
                   {"templateId":3,"color":"blue"},
                   {"templateId":4,"color":"dark blue"}
                 ];

   $scope.options =   {  
            "for offer": 
                 [
                   {"templateId":1,"color":"yellow"},
                   {"templateId":2,"color":"dark yellow"}
                 ],

           "no offer": 
                 [
                    {"templateId":3,"color":"blue"},
                    {"templateId":4,"color":"dark blue"}
                 ],

           "general": 
                 [
                    {"templateId":5,"color":"orange"},
                    {"templateId":6,"color":"dark orange"}
                 ]
        };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ngOptions` you can use `track by` to determine an unique identifier to bind value properly. Also, the value mustn't be a string, it have to be an object like so:

```
$scope.data3 = { templateId :"001" , color : "yellow"};
```

And your template:

```
<select name="third"
    ng-model="data3"
    ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in options track by value.templateId">
    <option value="">Select template</option>
</select>
```

Using `track by value.templateId` will tell `ngOptions` to look at the property `value.templateId` when testing the equality of the objects and determine selected value.

Updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcfLn4xg/7/).

Comment: thanks @LenilsonDeCastro, I wrote the solution based on this answer too

Comment: Glad that I could help. Also, you can accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: sorry because my late answer. I'm not sure if I should accept your answer even though it's true and the right answer (added into edited question) is based on it. If you see my solution tracking is by property of an array, not just property, and I give accurate info about how pass the array. I hope you understand it. Anyway is you think I should accept your answer still, I have no problem to do it.

Comment: Well, if it is an acceptable answer, you should. But if it's not, you may accept other or provide by yourself a proper answer to the problem described in this question so then people can get help on a similar problem. Anyway, it's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this requirement you have to use track by in ng-select. The track by will help you in binding the select option with a value tag. You should also provide an Unique Id field to track the select option.

```
<select ng-model="data" ng-options="item.color for item in options  track by item.templateId">
</select>
```

In your controller the options object will be like this

```
$scope.options = [{ templateId :"001" , color : "yellow"}, 
                  { templateId :"002" , color : "red"} ,    
                  { templateId :"003" , color : "green"}];
```

In order to initialize the select option you can set the model by

```
$scope.data= $scope.options[0];
```

You can initialize the scope variable only if you use the track by property in select option. In your question the `templateId` is the unique id

Comment: thanks @Nitheesh, I wrote the solution based on this answer